# Error:** *FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: -- But the file is there

Tags: python, pandas

What is wrong with this code snippet?

```
filename = "https://...filepath.../auto.csv"

with open (filename) as readfile:
df = pd.read_csv(readfile)
```

**Error:** *FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:*

I am sure the file exists and is the right path because it works when I use this

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, names = headers)
```

Comment: The second way that works is the correct way to use pandas... why would you want to do it the first way? Also, indentation is very important when posting Python questions!

Comment: `open()` can only access a local file, i.e. something which exists on the disk of the computer you are currently using. The "filename" is a URL specifying a remote location, not a file in the local file system; so you can't `open()` that. Maybe try `requests` instead.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks. This seems to be the cause. I tried with local file, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The right use of pandas read is the latter though you can use that way like this

```
with open(filename) as readfile:
    df = pd.read_csv(readfile.read())
```

`pandas.read_csv()` method accepts `filepath_or_buffer` as an argument which is accepted refer to the following.

> Parameters:    filepath_or_buffer : str, path object or file-like object
>   Any valid string path is acceptable. The string could be a URL. Valid
>   URL schemes include http, ftp, s3, and file. For file URLs, a host is
>   expected. A local file could be: file://localhost/path/to/table.csv.
>
> If you want to pass in a path object, pandas accepts any os.PathLike.
>
> By file-like object, we refer to objects with a read() method, such as
>   a file handler (e.g. via builtin open function) or StringIO.

You can check the full documentation for read_csv method [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).